# customizing the change password page in communities

Tags: visualforce, community, change-password

Hi I'm working on communities and would like to customize the change password page that is displayed to the customer after a password reset. This is the url to the default changepassword- **/_ui/system/security/ChangePassword**.  I have customized the changepassword vf page that Salesforce provides but when I try to test it out it still takes me back to the same old SF default changepassword. After much digging it appears to me that the changepassword vf page that's provided with the communities is tied to the user's personal profile. My question is where is the right page that needs to be customized or how can I make the change password link take the user to the custom page. Or is it even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the community is using the ChangePassword page and not ChatterAnswersChangePassword? Because I know the community is related to chatter

Comment: Otherwise you could use "URL redirect" in the Site config. Not the best practice but should work : IF url = /_ui/system.security/ChangePassword redirect to /My_Change_Password

Comment: @brovasi it's not using the ChangePassword page as I found that out when I was doing the changes to it. I will try your suggestions and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: why you are using vf page in salesforce?

Comment: pradeep my use of the vf page was to have a custom page that had the same functionality as the ChangePassword page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok guys. Thanks to my colleague, Rob who got on the Salesforce team at dreamforce to show how this could be done there is Great news!!! You would need to turn **Chatter answers** on in your SF org and then enable it for your communities(under site settings). Once this is done you can choose the visualforce page you want to use as your change password page. And voila. That's it!!! Just wished SF did better with their documentations for some of their products.

Comment: When I click on changepassword button on ChatterAnswersChangePassword I am getting an error "Your access is not allowed. Contact your site administrator."I don't see any logs against user

Comment: @sf.dev - i really am not sure why you maybe getting that error. Are you an admin for your org?

Comment: Not worked for me.. I am already able to see option to update Change Password page. Welcome email is taking me to standard ChangePassword page not to ovrrideed page which i have set on Community settings

Answer (score 5):

Really old question, this, but the solution of enabling Chatter Answers is now out of date. From Summer '16 Release Notes:

> Starting in Summer ’16, Chatter Answers isn’t available in new orgs.

But, it is now much simpler. Go to Setup->Build->Customize->Communities->All Communities. Then click Manage for your Community. In the community manager, go to Administration->Login & Registration and you will find a field for Change Password, where you can pick a Visualforce page.

Comment: Is there anyway that we can redirect to another VF page, if the link has already been used once?

Answer (score 2):

Made some progress on this issue. You can't actually customize the default ChangePassword and so what you could do is create your custom visualforce page with the controller to handle how you want your users password to be authenticated.

Next go to Personal setup => Email => Unfiled Public Email Templates. You can then customize the templates by removing the merge field {!Custom_url} and adding your link.

However, there is the issue of security here because usually the salesforce link the is sent to the user's email has an expiration time to it but with this approach I haven't quite figured out how this could be achieved. I guess I have my work cut out for me. Will do some more digging on this and add an update comment later.

Comment: Thanks for the research.  What is not clear to me is how to get the new tempoary password.  With communities the forgot your password email template sent out includes a link with confirmation token and no temporary password.

Comment: @Phil R - I'm not exactly sure I follow you. Are you referring to a kinda self-service whereby the user can sign up and receive temporary password and then change to a permanent password on signup?