# Default 'Change Password' page in Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to create a custom lightning component or VF Page just like below

Default 'ChangePassword' page in community.

[image]

I know that this is a standard page which we cannot modify in salesforce, that's why i wanted to create a lightning component/VF Page which should replicate the above page.

Can you help me to find the code for this page?

From where I can see the code for this page? or create a lightning component/VF Page for this.

Regards,
Pravindra

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17571/customizing-the-change-password-page-in-communities  check this

Comment: Can you please share the lightning component code corresponding to 'changepassword' default page, if you can?

Comment: No .. sorry

now i have one other question.

How to display the username information from the welcome email link to lightning component dynamically?